# Switching Background Images

Tags: java, android, eclipse, animation, background

please, i try to switch background images of the main activity of my application. I have no error during the compilation (API21 with eclipse) but it always crashes on emulator.

I've use this:

1-create a xml file with my images in the drawable folder like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/drink" android:duration="400" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/food" android:duration="400" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/restaurant" android:duration="400" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/hair" android:duration="400" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shop" android:duration="400" />
</animation-list>
```

2- create a viewswitcher layout for my activity;

and 3- create a main java file with this function :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewSwitcher img = (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.backimage);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backanim);

     // Get the AnimationDrawable object.
     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

     // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
     frameAnimation.start(); 
}
```

Can anyone help please????

Comment: Please share logcat.
Why using View Switcher ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace ViewSwitcher by ImageView as this (replace also it in your layout):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backimage);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.backanim);
AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) imageViewAnimation.getDrawable();
animation.start();
```

ViewSwitcher is for switch between two views, not switch between drawable.